# Twitter Boostrap - Align label horizontally to dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have the label for the dropdown next to the dropdown menus.

Find below how my current example looks like:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">Order: </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ticker<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions how to align the label with the dropdown properly?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but for alignment I would use a flexbox.

```css
.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">Order: </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Ticker
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Great answer, definitely gets my vote.  Another option is `align-items: baseline` in case you don't want to center the content.

The core issue here is that you're trying to align one item that has no vertical padding with another that has lots of padding.  Flexbox is one of the best ways to handle situations like this one.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the below css in your custom css file

```
.nav-pills>li:not(.dropdown) {
    padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```css
.nav-pills>li:not(.dropdown) {
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">Order: </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ticker<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add padding like this :

```css
/* Optional theme */

@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

ul.nav > li:first-child {
 padding:10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" >Order: </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Ticker
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: This is definitely the most simple solution out of all of the recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Use Flex to nav pills

```
.nav-pills{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/qfwngj5x/1/ for your reference

Answer (score 1):

I like Gerard's `display: flex` solution better, but just in case anyone prefers to maintain the original display property, here is an example using only `line-height` to vertically center both `.nav-pills`.

```html
<style>
    .nav-pills > li {
        line-height: 40px;
    }
    .nav.nav-pills > li > a {
        /* removes top & bottom padding */
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
</style>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">Order: </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ticker<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```